# How to refresh kafka queue once our data has been processed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a kafka producer with 4 topics. When I upload a CSV according to the type of CSV I will send it to the consumer based on its topic. For the first time if I do upload it will work great BUT once I upload another CSV it will upload the previous data as well and then it will put new CSV data.

I'm new to kafka so I was unable to find a proper solution regarding this problem. I tried searching for offset but was unable to implement it. I tried resetting the array back to null but after resetting to null when the new files come they have the previous as well as the new data in them.

> Code of Producer.js

```
 var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
        HighLevelProducer = kafka.HighLevelProducer,
        HighLevelConsumer = kafka.HighLevelConsumer,
        client = new kafka.Client(),
        producer = new HighLevelProducer(client),
        fs = require('fs'),
        consumer = new HighLevelConsumer(client, [{ topic: 'csvDealData', partition: 0 }, { topic: 'csvAssetData', partition: 0 }, { topic: 'csvPricingData', partition: 0 }, { topic: 'csvRedeemData', partition: 0 }], { autoCommit: false });
    var payloads;

var async = require('async');
console.log("STARTING PRODUCER");
var config = require("./config.json")
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = '9094';
let tempCSVArray = [];
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(port);
server.timeout = 24000;
var totalDataLength = 0;
var tempIndex;

// var offset = new kafka.Offset(client)
// offset.fetchLatestOffsets([topic], (err, offsets) => {
//     if (err) {
//         console.log(`error fetching latest offsets ${err}`)
//         return
//     }
//     var latest = 1
//     Object.keys(offsets[topic]).forEach( o => {
//         latest = offsets[topic][o] > latest ? offsets[topic][o] : latest
//     })
//     console.log(" topic :::  "+topic);
//     console.log(" offsets :::  "+offsets);
//     console.log(" latest :::  "+latest);
//     consumer.setOffset(topic, 0, latest-1)
// });

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, function () {
    console.log("Connected To Invoke Server.... ");
});
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('csvDataFromUI', function (data) {
        producer.on('error', function (err) { });
        tempCSVArray.push(data.dataArr);

        // here we are getting all the rows from CSV and we wait for the end line to come once we recived it we create and array and then send it tp and async function
        if (data.isEnd) {
            totalDataLength = tempCSVArray.length
            console.log(" \n length of data send to invoke function is ::::: " + totalDataLength + " \n  dataArray value :::: " + JSON.stringify(tempCSVArray));
            csvInvoke(tempCSVArray);
        }
    });
})

function csvInvoke(tempCSVArray) {
    async.eachOfSeries(tempCSVArray, (a, index, asyncCallback) => {
        a = a[0];
        tempIndex = index;
        let csvType = a.CsvType;
        if (csvType === "DealCaptureUpload") {
            var message = a;
            var originator = a.RepoData[0].Party[0].ParticipantID.trim();
            var collection = a.Collection;
            console.log(" originator  :::: " + originator);
            console.log("\nCollection: " + collection);
            if (a.RepoData[0].Trade[0].TransactionStatus == "NEW") {
                var newdata = { "originator": originator, "peers": ["0.0.0.0:" + config.peerPort[0][originator]], "channelName": "globalchannel", "chaincodeName": "DealPrivateCC", "fcn": "invoke", "Invokeargs": ["Capture", collection, message, "NEW", "DealPrivateCC", "globalchannel"], "username": "adminY", "orgName": config.orgList[0][originator] };
                payloads = [{ topic: 'csvDealData', messages: JSON.stringify(newdata), partition: 0, originator: originator }];
            } else if (a.RepoData[0].Trade[0].TransactionStatus == "CANCEL") {
                var newdata = { "originator": originator, "peers": ["0.0.0.0:" + config.peerPort[0][originator]], "channelName": "globalchannel", "chaincodeName": "DealPrivateCC", "fcn": "invoke", "Invokeargs": ["Capture", collection, message, "CANCEL", "PartyPrivateCC", "globalchannel"], "username": "adminY", "orgName": config.orgList[0][originator] };
                payloads = [{ topic: 'csvDealData', messages: JSON.stringify(newdata), partition: 0, originator: originator }];
            }
            setTimeout(() => {
                producer.send(payloads, function (err, data) {
                    if (err != null)
                        console.log("Error sending payload to consumer - " + err)
                    else
                        console.log("\n index ::: " + tempIndex + "\n Payloads  ::::::::  " + JSON.stringify(payloads));
                });
                asyncCallback();
            }, 6000);
        } else if (csvType === "AssetIssuanceUpload") {
            var message = a.Record[0];
            var originator = a.Party.trim();
            var collection = a.Collection;
            console.log(" \n originator  :::: " + originator);
            console.log("\n Collection: " + collection);
            var newdata = { "originator": originator, "peers": ["0.0.0.0:" + config.peerPort[0][originator]], "channelName": "globalchannel", "chaincodeName": "OwnershipPrivateCC", "fcn": "invokeInternal", "Invokeargs": ["Creation", collection, message], "username": "adminY", "orgName": config.orgList[0][originator] };
            payloads = [{ topic: 'csvAssetData', messages: JSON.stringify(newdata), partition: 0, originator: originator }];
            setTimeout(() => {
                producer.send(payloads, function (err, data) {
                    if (err != null)
                        console.log("Error sending payload to consumer - " + err)
                    else
                        console.log("\n index ::: " + tempIndex + "\n Payloads  ::::::::  " + JSON.stringify(payloads));
                });
                asyncCallback();
            }, 500);
        } else if (csvType === "PricingDataUpload") {
            var message = a.Record[0];
            var originator = a.Party.trim();
            console.log(" \n originator  :::: " + originator);
            var newdata = { "originator": originator, "peers": ["0.0.0.0:" + config.peerPort[0][originator]], "channelName": "globalchannel", "chaincodeName": "DataCC", "fcn": "invoke", "Invokeargs": ["DataSetup", message], "username": "adminY", "orgName": config.orgList[0][originator] };
            payloads = [{ topic: 'csvPricingData', messages: JSON.stringify(newdata), partition: 0, originator: originator }];
            setTimeout(() => {
                producer.send(payloads, function (err, data) {
                    if (err != null)
                        console.log("Error sending payload to consumer - " + err)
                    else
                        console.log("\n index ::: " + index + "\n Payloads  ::::::::  " + JSON.stringify(payloads));
                });
                asyncCallback();
            }, 500);
        } else if (csvType === "RedeemDataUpload") {
            var message = a.Record[0];
            var originator = a.Party.trim();
            var collection = a.Collection;
            console.log(" \n originator  :::: " + originator);
            console.log("\n Collection: " + collection);
            var newdata = { "originator": originator, "peers": ["0.0.0.0:" + config.peerPort[0][originator]], "channelName": "globalchannel", "chaincodeName": "PrivateCC", "fcn": "invoke", "Invokeargs": ["invokeWithdrawal", collection, message, "OwnershipPrivateCC"], "username": "adminY", "orgName": config.orgList[0][originator] };
            payloads = [{ topic: 'csvRedeemData', messages: JSON.stringify(newdata), partition: 0, originator: originator }];
            setTimeout(() => {
                producer.send(payloads, function (err, data) {
                    if (err != null)
                        console.log("Error sending payload to consumer - " + err)
                    else
                        console.log("\n index ::: " + index + "\n Payloads  ::::::::  " + JSON.stringify(payloads));
                });
                asyncCallback();
            }, 2000);
        }

        if (index === totalDataLength - 1) {
            tempCSVArray = [];
            //a = [];
            payloads = [];
            console.log(" We are flushing the tempCSVArray  ::::");
            console.log("\n final tempCSVArray  ::: " + JSON.stringify(tempCSVArray) + "    final a :::::: final  payloads ::::: " + JSON.stringify(payloads))

        }
        client.refreshMetadata(['csvDealData', 'csvAssetData', 'csvPricingData', 'csvRedeemData'], (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.warn('Error refreshing kafka metadata', err);
            }
        });

    }, function (err) {
        if (err) console.error(err.message);
        console.warn('Error refreshing kafka metadata', err);
    });
}
```

> Code for Consumer

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');
var HighLevelConsumer = kafka.HighLevelConsumer;
var Client = kafka.Client;
var argv = require('optimist').argv;
var client = new Client('localhost:2181');
var topics = [{ topic: 'csvDealData' }, { topic: 'csvAssetData' }, { topic: 'csvPricingData' }, { topic: 'csvRedeemData' }];
var options = { autoCommit: true, fetchMaxWaitMs: 1000, fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 1024 };
var consumer = new HighLevelConsumer(client, topics, options);

console.log("STARTING CONSUMER");

var hfcSocket = require("socket.io-client");
var invoke1 = hfcSocket.connect('http://10.21.134.17:5001');
var invoke2 = hfcSocket.connect('http://10.21.134.17:5004');
var invoke3 = hfcSocket.connect('http://10.21.134.17:5005');
var invoke4 = hfcSocket.connect('http://10.21.134.17:5002');
var invoke5 = hfcSocket.connect('http://10.21.134.17:5006');
var invoke6 = hfcSocket.connect('http://10.21.134.17:5003');
var invoke7 = hfcSocket.connect('http://10.21.134.17:5007');
var invoke8 = hfcSocket.connect('http://10.21.134.17:5008');

consumer.on('message', function (message) {
   console.log(" message in consumer  :::: " + JSON.stringify(message));

   if (message.topic == "csvDealData") {
      console.log(" Message ::: " + JSON.stringify(message));
      var originator = JSON.parse(message.value).originator;
      if (originator == "Org1") 
            invoke1.emit('csvDealData', message)
      else if (originator == "Org2") 
            invoke2.emit('csvDealData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org3")
            invoke6.emit('csvDealData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org4") 
            invoke5.emit('csvDealData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org5") 
            invoke3.emit('csvDealData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org6") 
            invoke4.emit('csvDealData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org7") 
            invoke7.emit('csvDealData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org8") 
            invoke8.emit('csvDealData', message);
   } else if (message.topic == "csvAssetData") {
      var originator = JSON.parse(message.value).originator;
      if (originator == "Org1") 
            invoke1.emit('csvAssetData', message)
      else if (originator == "Org2") 
            invoke2.emit('csvAssetData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org3") 
            invoke6.emit('csvAssetData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org4") 
            invoke5.emit('csvAssetData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org5") 
            invoke3.emit('csvAssetData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org6") 
            invoke4.emit('csvAssetData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org7") 
            invoke7.emit('csvAssetData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org8")
            invoke8.emit('csvAssetData', message);
   } else if (message.topic == "csvPricingData") {
      var originator = JSON.parse(message.value).originator;
      if (originator == "Org1") 
            invoke1.emit('csvPricingData', message)
      else if (originator == "Org2")
            invoke2.emit('csvPricingData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org3") 
            invoke6.emit('csvPricingData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org4") 
            invoke5.emit('csvPricingData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org5") 
            invoke3.emit('csvPricingData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org6") 
            invoke4.emit('csvPricingData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org7") 
            invoke7.emit('csvPricingData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org8")
            invoke8.emit('csvPricingData', message);
   } else if (message.topic == "csvRedeemData") {
      var originator = JSON.parse(message.value).originator;
      if (originator == "Org1") 
            invoke1.emit('csvRedeemData', message)
      else if (originator == "Org2") 
            invoke2.emit('csvRedeemData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org3")
            invoke6.emit('csvRedeemData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org4") 
            invoke5.emit('csvRedeemData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org5") 
            invoke3.emit('csvRedeemData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org6") 
            invoke4.emit('csvRedeemData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org7") 
            invoke7.emit('csvRedeemData', message);
      else if (originator == "Org8") 
            invoke8.emit('csvRedeemData', message);
   }
});

consumer.on('error', function (err) {
   console.log('error', err);
});
```

I was expecting if the user has already uploaded a CSV and uploads another type of CSV it should not hamper the data of the previous CSV and then it should also send the new CSV properly without calling the previous data.

[my fiddle link for producer.js](https://jsfiddle.net/w4jbtq2h/)

[link for consumer](https://jsfiddle.net/1fj6g4yp/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get data from a CSV file into Kafka, use Kafka Connect. There's [a connector](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir) that will ingest CSV files. Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka, and just requires simple JSON configuration to use.

Comment: thanks but i 'm already able to get row by row data till kafka it's just now i want to figure out how i can remove the data of previous csv from the queue to make way for other CSv data once older one is complete.